# How to modify the axis of the Taylor diagram with correlations that vary from -1 to 1?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am planning to plot a Taylor diagram in Python, using the `easy_mpl` library. I used the following code and was able to generate a Taylor diagram:

```
import numpy as np
from easy_mpl import taylor_plot
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from easy_mpl.utils import version_info

version_info()

df = pd.read_csv("G:\Python\Taylor_plot.csv")

data = df.to_numpy()

observations =  data[:, 0]
simulations =  {"Model-1": data[:, 1],
            "Model-3": data[:, 2],
            "Model-3": data[:, 3],
            "Model-4": data[:, 4],
            "Model-5": data[:,5],
            "Model-6": data[:,6],
            "Model-7": data[:,7],
            "Model-8": data[:,8],}
_ = taylor_plot(observations=observations,
            simulations=simulations,
            plot_bias=True,
            cont_kws={'colors': '#1A74A5', 'linewidths': 1.5},
            grid_kws={'axis': 'x', 'color': '#5CB994', 'lw': 2.0, 'ls': 'dotted'},             
            marker_kws={'markersize': 10, 'markeredgewidth': 1.0,
                        'markeredgecolor': 'black', 'lw': 0.0},
            title="Taylor Plot")
```

I noticed that Models 7 and 8 are missing from the plot. I hypothesized that their values might be negative or outside the first quadrant.

Therefore, I would like to know how to add other quadrants to the Taylor diagram to show negative correlation values.

This is a sample from the data I used:

```
[[2.614  0.282  0.901  0.254  0.42   0.785  0.4871 0.6842 1.0216]
 [3.141  0.265  0.717  0.245  0.46   0.6122 0.5516 0.6457 0.5939]
 [0.563  0.282  0.661  0.252  1.81   0.636  0.4983 0.6041 0.5376]
 [2.343  0.292  0.563  0.289  0.6    0.4559 0.515  0.4323 0.65  ]
 [0.893  0.276  0.538  0.248  0.37   0.3996 0.4455 0.3962 0.5438]
 [0.426  0.253  0.637  0.248  0.42   0.5251 0.4136 0.4809 0.5804]
 [8.563  0.39   1.192  0.308  0.61   1.0787 1.1276 0.8346 0.5782]
 [2.213  0.499  1.587  0.279  0.88   1.2618 1.6147 1.1937 1.0943]
 [3.065  1.728  1.728  4.059  1.1    1.4816 1.5246 1.275  3.4991]
 [9.223  2.045  2.045  8.701  0.86   2.1728 4.8029 2.3691 0.9047]]
```

This is an example of the figure I would like to plot: [same figure but in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999338/r-taylor-diagram-plotting)